# How many Windows wall clock seconds are there in an actual second?

Tags: python, time, clock

This code:

```
import random,time
raw_input()

while True:   
    try:
        TIME += 0
    except:
        TIME = time.clock() 
    x = random.random()
    if x > 0.999999:
        print x
        print time.clock()-TIME
        break
```

Provided this output:

```
0.999999910337
63.5525445557
```

However, I tested on a stopwatch and I seemed to get a second and 3 quarters on the stopwatch. I wasn't going for an accurate reading, I was simply trying to figure out how many Windows wall clock seconds there are to every second.

2nd Try

```
0.999999028728
0.93168230208
```

Took a second and a quarter

I kept getting weird answers. Anyway, does anybody know? Or is it a rate?

Comment: On Windows [`time.clock()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) is wall time (ie actual seconds). There is one "Windows wall clock second" to every actual second. I'm not sure why you're getting a discrepancy, it is working fine for me.

Comment: OK thanks. Maybe the discrepancy is a measure of my poor reaction time!!!

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the execution time of some of the functions I'm making.